# Run-time error 1004 for Refresh Pivot Table

Tags: vba, excel, refresh, pivot-table

I created macro which would refresh all pivot tables in a worksheet. The same code works on one sheet however doesn't on the other. I tried to run it in debug mode and it works fine for first few tables and crush on one in the middle with error:

> Run-time error '1004': RefreshTable method of PivotTable class
>   failed.

There are 20 Pivot Tables in this sheet, but on the one where it works are 26. Your help would be much appreciated.

```
Sub Refresh_Pivots2()

Dim PL As PivotTable

Worksheets("Incidents Pivots").Activate

    For Each PL In ActiveSheet.PivotTables

    PL.RefreshTable

    Next PL

End Sub
```

I just tried another code

```
Sub Refresh_Incidents()

Worksheets("Incidents Pivots").Activate

Dim A

A = Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20")

For i = 0 To 19

ActiveSheet.PivotTables(A(i)).RefreshTable

Next i

End Sub
```

if I start from i=0 it gives an error but when switch it to i=1 it works. Any ideas what is wrong with this table. I am able to refresh it manually.

Comment: Can you refresh them all manually?

Comment: Hi Rory, yes I can refresh each of this table manually.

Comment: So if you use Refresh All, you don't get an error?

Comment: Once I go one by one and refresh then it works. Is that want you mean?

Comment: No, I mean if you press the Refresh All button on the data tab, do you get an error?

Comment: Sorry just got your point, once I click Refresh all it works. Also when I use simple macro `ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll` also works.

Comment: What does `Msgbox ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).SourceData` return?

Comment: For  Pivot table "1" it returns 'Data Dump'!$A:$N for all other 'Data Dump'!C1:C14

Comment: But when I go to Change Data Source each table has the same A:N

Comment: That is strange as SourceData should return a reference in R1C1 notation, not A1. Can you run: `ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).SourceData = 'Data Dump'!C1:C14` and then refresh the pivot table without error?

Comment: It not allows to use that, I added quotation marks and checked by MsgBox and source was still the same.

Comment: I just checked the Excel Options ->Formulas and R1C1 reference style was switched of, so I turn it on and macro works!!! Thanks for your help Rory!

Answer (score 2):

As Rory suggested there was something wrong with source data for one table, it used A1 instead of R1C1 notation. I changed it in Excel Option->Formulas->R1C1 reference style and now macro works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the pivot table datasource. also some time this kind of issues happen due to pivot cache. call the below code before refreshing the pivots.

```
Sub PivotCacheClear()
    Dim pc As PivotCache
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    With ActiveWorkbook
        For Each pc In .PivotCaches
            pc.MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsNone
        Next pc
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Raja Thevar, thanks for your reply, I used your code and after that i run my macro and got the same error. Source is the same for each table on this sheet so is fine for sure. As I mentioned above I am able to refresh this table manually. The moment when i get this error is on this part of code    PL.RefreshTable

Comment: Yes, I am able to refresh it manually. Also if I would ask about this particular table in macro and will refresh then it it works.

Comment: Tried this before and now and it come back with same error. Looks like it don't want to refresh PivotTable("1"), because when I code `Sub Refresh_Incidents()

Worksheets("Incidents Pivots").Activate

Dim A

A = Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20")

For i = 0 To 19

ActiveSheet.PivotTables(A(i)).RefreshTable

Next i

End Sub` then it give the same error. But when I change `For i=1 ...` then it works. Any ideas what might be wrong with this table?

Comment: Instead of using array you can directly use for loop with i =1 to 20

Comment: I can but tables are not in index order so it is easier to track them by name.

Answer (score 0):

I have a code that auto adjust the data from a Pivot Table and then refresh the Pivot Table, may be it can halp you:

```
Sub AdjustPivotDataRange(ByVal SheetName As String)

Dim Data_sht As Worksheet
Dim Pivot_sht As Worksheet
Dim StartPoint As Range
Dim DataRange As Range
Dim PivotName As String
Dim NewRange As String

  Sheets("All 2014 to Current Date").Visible = True
'Set Variables Equal to Data Sheet and Pivot Sheet
  Set Data_sht = Worksheets("All 2014 to Current Date")
  Set Pivot_sht = Worksheets(SheetName)

'Enter in Pivot Table Name
  PivotName = "PivotTable1"

'Dynamically Retrieve Range Address of Data
  Set StartPoint = Data_sht.Range("A6")
  LastRow = Data_sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  LastColumn = Data_sht.Cells(LastRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
  Data_sht.Activate
  Set DataRange = Data_sht.Range(StartPoint, Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))

  NewRange = Data_sht.Name & "!" & _
    DataRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

'Make sure every column in data set has a heading and is not blank (error prevention)
  If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(DataRange.Rows(1)) > 0 Then
    MsgBox "One of your data columns has a blank heading." & vbNewLine _
      & "Please fix and re-run!.", vbCritical, "Column Heading Missing!"
    Exit Sub
  End If

'Change Pivot Table Data Source Range Address
  Pivot_sht.PivotTables(PivotName).ChangePivotCache _
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=NewRange)

'Ensure Pivot Table is Refreshed
  Pivot_sht.PivotTables(PivotName).RefreshTable
  Sheets("Rolling 12-mo.").Select
  Sheets("All 2014 to Current Date").Visible = False
'Complete Message
  'MsgBox PivotName & "'s data source range has been successfully updated!"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`connection property`=>`usage`=>`enable background refresh`, please make sure, that it has not been selected.