# Runtime Error appearing only on specific computer

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following macro in a file used also by other colleagues.

```
Sub Bucket_on_parts()
If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents = False Then
  Dim pT As PivotTable
  Dim lastRow, lastRowHere, lastRowSummary As Long
  Dim FMList, checkAIR, checkSummary As String
  'clear content
  Sheets("Pivot").Visible = True
  Sheets("Pivot").Range("L4:L978").Clear
  Sheets("summary").Range("A2:D976").Clear

  Set pT = Sheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable2")
  lastRow = Sheets("overview").Range("G1000").End(xlUp).Row
  lastRowHere = Sheets("query").Range("D1000").End(xlUp).Row
  If lastRow < 14 Then
    MsgBox ("no data to work on")
    Sheets("Pivot").Visible = 2
    Exit Sub
  Else
    With pT
        'Update the pivot table
        .PivotCache.Refresh
        'clear all filters
        .PivotFields("Accepted").ClearAllFilters
        'filters only accepted items
        .PivotFields("Accepted").CurrentPage = "YES"
    [...]
 End Sub
```

When I run it on my computer it goes smoothly.

When a colleague runs it on his own computer, he constantly gets a

```
Run-time error '1004': 
Application-defined or object-defined error
```

on `.pivotCache.Refresh`

I have tried using his own file on my computer, and I get no error.
If I run the macro step by step on his computer, I see this detailed error message:

[image]

Any idea on how to tackle the issue?

Comment: Have you seen [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34509313/run-time-error-1004-for-refresh-pivot-table)

Comment: @SiddharthRout, it doesn't look the same issue (sub code of runtime error is different). Moreove, manual refresh of the pivot table fails.