# Run-time error 1004: RefreshTable method of PivotTable class failed

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I'm trying to create a macro to refresh automatically some pivot tables once it's click all in the same tab. When I run the macro I get that error msg. If I refresh them manually one by one it works fine. Also using F8 I see that the problem comes after the third PT. Any idea how to solve it?

```
Sub RefreshPivotTables() 

Dim PL as PivotTable

Worksheets("Overview"). Activate 

 For Each PL in ActiveSheet. PivotTables

    PL.RefreshTable
    Next PL

End Sub
```

Comment: What's different about the third pivot table? Is it a different range? Based on a dynamic named range? You could add `On Error Resume Next` and log the error for that one (or any) pivot table refresh that fails, this way you refresh all of the tables that are possible and then can focus on why particular PTs fail.

Comment: Yes, every table have a different range, this range is fix for all of them as well as the name. I added it but this only goes to the next one without error, not really solving it as I would like to refresh as well this third one

Comment: This still indicates that there's something different about PT 3, likely having to do with the source range. Try some debug statements that print out the source range for each table, then specifically check the range for PT3 and make sure it matches. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34513474/4717755) may also provide some dynamic help in re-setting the range before the refresh. I'm afraid that without having much more information about your pivot tables, ranges, and code we won't be able to help much more than this without more detailed information.